# Scope of a variable in Insertion Sort code

Tags: javascript, scope

I came across a working code for insertion sort which is as follows:

```
function insertionSort(array) {
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
       let curr = array[i];
       for (var j = i-1; j >= 0 && array[j] > curr; j--){
          array[j+1] = array[j];
       }
       array[j+1] = curr;
    }
    return array;
}
```

My question is: shouldn't the j in the line:

```
array[j+1] = curr;
```

be out of scope?
What am I missing here?

Comment: It's always better to start a variable with `const` identifier and make it `let` as necessary.  `var` scope is function scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring javascript variables using `var` makes the scope of the variable be the bounds of the entire function it is declared inside.

Opposed to `let`, which restricts the scope to the block it is defined inside.

So, no. It will not be out of scope.